# Jumping on the clouds

Tags: programming-challenge, interview-questions, swift

I have started the Hackerrank interview preparation kit. The [first problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem) I have solved with Swift is as follows:

> Emma is playing a new mobile game that starts with consecutively numbered clouds. Some of the clouds are thunderheads and others are cumulus. She can jump on any cumulus cloud having a number that is equal to the number of the current cloud plus 1 or 2. She must avoid the thunderheads. Determine the minimum number of jumps it will take Emma to jump from her starting position to the last cloud.
>
> For each game, Emma will get an array of clouds numbered 0 if they are safe or 1 if they must be avoided.

```
func jumpingOnClouds(c: [Int]) -> Int {
    var jump = 0
    var location = 0
    repeat {
        if (location + 2 < c.count) && 
        (c[location + 2] == 0) {
            location += 2
        } else {
            location += 1
        }
        if location >= c.count {
            break
        }
        jump += 1
    } while location < c.count
    return jump
}
```

It's time complexity is \$O(n)\$. Are there any ways I could reduce this? I am also interested in improving the code quality. Are there ways I can take better advantage of Swift to improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is clearly written, and works correctly (to the best of my knowledge). I don't think that the time complexity is \$O(n)\$ can be improved, because the array must be traversed in order to locate the dangerous thunderheads. Your algorithm already optimizes that by checking only every second element (if that is a safe spot), relying on the fact that a solution is guaranteed.

The program can be improved a bit though. The `while location < c.count` condition of the main loop will always be true because the loop is always “early left” at

```
if location >= c.count {
    break
}
```

As a consequence, the program computes one location beyond the array bounds which is not needed (and not counted). This can be simplified by using a while-loop instead:

```
while location < c.count - 1 {
    if (location + 2 < c.count) &&
        (c[location + 2] == 0) {
        location += 2
    } else {
        location += 1
    }
    jump += 1
}
```

This is shorter and easier to understand because there is only one terminating condition for the loop instead of two.

A possible improvement *might* be to run the loop until one of the last *two* positions it reached, because then the test against the array count is done only once per iteration and not twice:

```
while location < c.count - 2 {
    if c[location + 2] == 0 {
        location += 2
    } else {
        location += 1
    }
    jump += 1
}
return location == c.count - 1 ? jump : jump + 1
```

A further optimization would be to use that if we do a size 1 jump because of a thunderhead, the following jump will always be of size 2:

```
while location < c.count - 2 {
    if c[location + 2] == 0 {
        // Jump two positions:
        location += 2
        jump += 1
    } else {
        // Jump one position and then two positions:
        location += 3
        jump += 2
    }
}
return location == c.count - 1 ? jump : jump + 1
```

But the performance increase will probably be negligible since the arrays have at most 100 elements.

Some minor points: The parentheses in

```
if (location + 2 < c.count) &&
    (c[location + 2] == 0)
```

are not needed because the comparison operators have a higher precedence than the logical operators:

```
if location + 2 < c.count && c[location + 2] == 0
```

Finally, I would name the counter variable `jumps` or `jumpCount` to better describe its purpose.